# Is there a way to fix error: replacing existing signatureWarning: unable to build chain to self-signed root for signer (xamarin iOS)

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, mobile, app-store

Is there a way fix error:

```
/Users/pizhev/Documents/WeatherLocationInfo 1.5.7/WeatherLocationInfo.iOS/bin/iPhone/Release/WeatherLocationInfo.iOS.app/Frameworks/libSkiaSharp.framework/libSkiaSharp: 

Error: /Users/pizhev/Documents/WeatherLocationInfo 1.5.7/WeatherLocationInfo.iOS/bin/iPhone/Release/WeatherLocationInfo.iOS.app/Frameworks/libSkiaSharp.framework/libSkiaSharp: replacing existing signature
    
Warning: unable to build chain to self-signed root for signer "Apple Distribution: Blagovest Pizhev (UJ3Z6JFQ92)"

/Users/pizhev/Documents/WeatherLocationInfo 1.5.7/WeatherLocationInfo.iOS/bin/iPhone/Release/WeatherLocationInfo.iOS.app/Frameworks/libSkiaSharp.framework/libSkiaSharp: errSecInternalComponent (WeatherLocationInfo.iOS)
```

I create and Install a clean new certificates from apple.

[image: Certificates]

I create and Install a clean new provisioning profiles from apple.

[image: Provisioning profile]

I use correctly my App ID Configuration.

[image: My App ID Configuration]

When I logged into my apple id on Visual Studio and xCode I see my new certificates and provisioning profiles.

On my info.plist in Visual Studio I write `pizhevsoft.WeatherLocationInfo` on CFBundleIdentifier and write `WeatherLocationInfo` on CFBundleDisplayName and use `WeatherLocationInfo` on CFBundleName.

[image: My info.plist]

I set on all certificates - Always Trust and still don't know why this error display when I try to build for Apple Store.

[image: My Keychain Access Certificates]

I don't know What can I do to fix this error.

Is there something I'm missing ?

I have completed the steps for creating new certificates and provisioning profiles more than 20 times and each time the result is the same.

I really need professional help to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3):

Mayeb a root certificate(**Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority**) is missing from the system.

> The current Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Intermediate Certificate (intermediate certificate) is set to expire on February 7, 2023. The renewed certificate will be used to sign new software signing certificates issued after January 28, 2021 for the Apple Developer Programs. Remaining service certificates will be updated in the future and this page will be updated to reflect additional certificate changes.

You could have a try with [Apple Document](https://developer.apple.com/support/expiration/) to take action to download [it](https://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/AppleWWDRCAG3.cer).

I delete the oldest certificate (Worldwide Developer) and install the new one from your link, but error is the same and still there:

```
/Users/pizhev/Documents/WeatherLocationInfo 1.5.7/WeatherLocationInfo.iOS/bin/iPhone/Release/WeatherLocationInfo.iOS.app/Frameworks/libSkiaSharp.framework/libSkiaSharp: Error: /Users/pizhev/Documents/WeatherLocationInfo 1.5.7/WeatherLocationInfo.iOS/bin/iPhone/Release/WeatherLocationInfo.iOS.app/Frameworks/libSkiaSharp.framework/libSkiaSharp: replacing existing signature
    Warning: unable to build chain to self-signed root for signer "Apple Distribution: Blagovest Pizhev (UJ3Z6JFQ92)"
    /Users/pizhev/Documents/WeatherLocationInfo 1.5.7/WeatherLocationInfo.iOS/bin/iPhone/Release/WeatherLocationInfo.iOS.app/Frameworks/libSkiaSharp.framework/libSkiaSharp: errSecInternalComponent (WeatherLocationInfo.iOS)
```

[image: G3 Certificate Worldwide]

Comment: Do you kno how to fix that ?

Comment: @RositsaV You could have a check with [this discussion](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/86161). If you miss the root certificate, you need to download it and install it manually. But here I found that the certificate also has been installed. You could make it be installed in `System` group to check.

Comment: I install all my certs in system now, but the error is still the same..